# How do I list all streams and continuous views in pipelinedb?

Tags: postgresql, pipelinedb

In pipelinedb I can't seem to locate a way to list all of the streams and continuous views that I've created.

I can back into the CVs by looking for the "mrel" tables that are created but it's kind of clunky.

Is there a system table or view I can query that will list them?

Comment: The docs say that: `SELECT * FROM pipeline.pipeline_views();` should work but the function doesn't exist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have an older version of pipelinedb, or you may be looking at an older version of the docs.

You can check your version with psql like so:

```
pipeline=# select * from pipeline_version();
                                                                     pipeline_version                                                                      
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 PipelineDB 0.9.0 at revision b1ea9ab6acb689e6ed69fb26af555ca8d025ebae on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04) 4.8.4, 64-bit
(1 row)
```

In the latest version, information about views can be obtained like so:

```
pipeline=# select * from pipeline_views();
 id | schema | name |         query         
----+--------+------+-----------------------
 11 | public | cv   |  SELECT x::integer,  +
    |        |      |     count(*) AS count+
    |        |      |    FROM ONLY s       +
    |        |      |   GROUP BY x::integer
(1 row)
```

Information about streams can be obtained like so:

```
pipeline=# select * from pipeline_streams();
 schema | name | inferred | queries |                tup_desc                
--------+------+----------+---------+----------------------------------------
 public | s    | t        | {cv}    | \x000000017800000006a4ffffffff00000000
(1 row)
```

More information can be obtained by using \d+:

```
pipeline=# \d+ cv
             Continuous view "public.cv"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers | Storage | Description 
--------+---------+-----------+---------+-------------
 x      | integer |           | plain   | 
 count  | bigint  |           | plain   | 
View definition:
 SELECT x::integer,
    count(*) AS count
   FROM ONLY s
  GROUP BY x::integer;

pipeline=# \d+ s
                     Stream "public.s"
      Column       |            Type             | Storage 
-------------------+-----------------------------+---------
 arrival_timestamp | timestamp(0) with time zone | plain
```

Comment: Yep. I'm using an older version. That explains why I didn't see anything in the docs a few weeks ago. Time to upgrade. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's easy peasy,

just write

```
select * from pipeline_streams();
```

To see pipelinestreams and inside of it u can see which stream has which views.

Edit:
Above code snippet is only for 0.9.x version of PipelineDB since it is PostgreSQL extension with version 1.x you will use foreign tables as a streams

```
psql -c "\dE[S+];"
```

This code will show you all foreign tables on psql (Streams on pipelinedb).

For more information : http://docs.pipelinedb.com/streams.html